# ユーザーフォームでWebBrowserをクリックするとExcelが強制終了する

Tags: vba

VBAでユーザーフォームを作成し、そこにWebBrowserコントロールを貼り付けています。

WebBrowserでは、以下のコードでインターネット上の画像のURLにNavigateさせて、ユーザーフォーム上で画像を表示できるようにしております。

WebBrowser.Navigate "画像のURL"

こちら問題なく表示されるのですが、表示されたあと、WebBrowserの部分をマウスでクリックすると、Excelごと強制終了されるという問題が発生しております。。

こちら、何か原因や対処法など、ご存知の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

こういった問題が起きないWebBrowserの代替品があればと思って探しているのですが、見つかっておりません。（WebView2はVBAでは使えない認識です。）

また、WebBrowserの部分を何か別のコントロールで覆ってしまって、クリックできないようにしようかとも考えたのですが、LabelやImageで覆ってもクリックできてしまい、Frameで覆うとクリックはできなくなりましたが、WebBrowserが見えなくなってしまって本末転倒でした。

何か情報がございましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: これらの記事が類似の話題を扱っているようでWebView2が使えるかもしれません。[Hosting Microsoft Edge via WebView2Loader.dll with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71550625/9014308) ,[Automate Chrome / Edge using VBA](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5307593/Automate-Chrome-Edge-using-VBA) あとAccessだと [EdgeBrowserControl オブジェクト (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/access.edgebrowsercontrol), [Use the Edge browser control on a form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/use-the-edge-browser-control-on-a-form-f9f731be-8f9b-4dd2-a5cb-525cfaed52d5) があるようです。

Comment: ちなみにブラウザ的な物を使う必要があるのでしょうか？ 指定されたファイルをダウンロードしてそれをイメージのオブジェクトとして読み込んで表示すれば良いのでは？ こちらの記事のように。[Load URL image into UserForm](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/load-url-image-into-userform.1060189/), [Get image url in excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71527664/9014308), [Working with images in VBA - Displaying PNG files](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/working-with-images-in-vba-displaying-png-files.1224206/) 色々と他にもあるでしょうから、目的に合ったものを探してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ご返信をありがとうございます。類似の記事のご紹介も大変ありがたいです。WebView2については、調べたところVBAでは使えなさそうでした。。

Comment: ご返信をありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り、ファイルをダウンロードしてからユーザーフォームで読み込んで表示することも可能です。ただ、表示したいファイルが大量にあるため、ダウンロードに時間がかかる問題があり、できればWebBrowserで表示したいと考えておりました。ほかの方法も再検討したいと思います。ありがとうございます。

Comment: ほぼ出来立て(まあ完全では無い)らしいプロジェクトが公開されているようです。[lucasplumb/ExcelWebView2](https://github.com/lucasplumb/ExcelWebView2), [Any interest in WebView2/Edge automation for Excel?](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/16uykx5/any_interest_in_webview2edge_automation_for_excel/), [ExcelWebView2 - an embedded Edge browser project in Excel](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/17otjrv/excelwebview2_an_embedded_edge_browser_project_in/)

Comment: ご返信をありがとうございます。Excel向けのWebView2もできたらしいという情報をありがとうございます！確認いたします。